# Why previously configured Facebook developes accounts react different from now configured accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I want some clarification about  Facebook graph API version2.2

I have 2 Facebook developer accounts, one which I configure before 2 year and 2nd I configure one week before. I get all friends successfully when we put credentials from 1st developer account that i configure 2 year before. but I get friends only that use developer account when we put credentials from 2nd developer account that i configure one week before.

In developer account both account have same user_friends permission default enabled.

When I fetch  permission through API request then 1st account shows basic_profile and user_friends enabled permission and 2nd account shows only basic_profile permission.
Can we get all friends information from current Facebook  API?
Any support and guide will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need permission approval from facebook to access anything other than basic_profile on non-developer accounts.

Comment: There is no permission for "user_friends" in the permission list. May be"user_friends" permission is not showing in my FB developer account.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ 
As of now you can only access those friends who are using the application.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because your old account was able to use the Facebook Graph API v1.0, which allowed retrieval of the complete friends list (without the `user_friends`) permission.

Accounts created after April 30th 2014 are locked to the newer Graph API v2.0 (or newer), which can only access friends using `user_friends` permission and is only able to access "mutual" friends (those friends that also have the app installed).